# mongodb second replica set all are secondaries

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset, mongodb-shell

I have created one replica set with the following commands

```
mongod --replSet s0  --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard0/rs0 --port 37017 --shardsvr 
mongod --replSet s0  --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard0/rs1 --port 37018 --shardsvr
mongod --replSet s0  --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard0/rs2 --port 37019 --shardsvr 

mongo --port 37017

config = { _id: "s0", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:37017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:37018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:37019" }]};


rs.initiate(config)
```

when I checked rs.status() it showing 1 primary and 2 secondaries.

**Second replica set:**

Now i tried to create second replica set with the following commands.

```
mongod --replSet s1   --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard1/rs0 --port 47017   --shardsvr 
mongod --replSet s1  --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard1/rs1 --port 47018   --shardsvr  
mongod --replSet s1  --dbpath E:/mongo/data/shard1/rs2 --port 47019   --shardsvr  


mongo --port 47017

config = { _id: "s1", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:47017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:47018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:47019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)
```

**when i checked rs.status() on second replica set its showing all are secondaries.**

why there is no primary on second replica set?

Anyone help me.Thank you

Comment: The commands and the steps you have posted are correct for both replica-sets. It generally takes few seconds  (5 to 10)  after the `rs.initiate()` for the current member to show as a PRIMARY, in the status.

Comment: @prasad_ After one hour also showing as secondary only.

Comment: Are all the members up running in the `s1` replica-set?

Comment: @prasad_All are up

Comment: Please update the question with the `rs.status` output.

Comment: @prasad_ Now I closed all command prompts.Executed all commands again its showing primary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204521/discussion-between-nithin-and-prasad).